# save images mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

schema

```
 images:{ type : Array , "default" : [] }
```

controller

```
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var dt = new Date(req.body.dateOfBirth)
            var experiences = new Experiences({
            'images': req.body.images

        });
        experiences.save(function(err,experiences){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve(experiences);
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to save more than one image into single **image**

posting Data as :

```
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/346768/pexels-photo-346768.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb","https://images.pexels.com/photos/287240/pexels-photo-287240.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
```

but when i viewing my document. getting result like this :

```
"images" : [ 
    "\"https://images.pexels.com/photos/346768/pexels-photo-346768.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb\",\"https://images.pexels.com/photos/287240/pexels-photo-287240.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb\""
]
```

what am i doing wrong please help?
i want result like:

```
"images" : [ 
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/346768/pexels-photo-346768.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb","https://images.pexels.com/photos/287240/pexels-photo-287240.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
]
```

Comment: how are you pushing data in images while sending?

Comment: `images:{ type : [String], "default" : [] }` and then `push` into this (image) array

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya I mentioned in question __posting Data as : __

Comment: @GeorgeBailey i am pushing as a string my images. then it gives me result like this. how do i push it as object?

Comment: What I am asking is show the code of how you are posting

Comment: `how do i push it as object?` --> You define an Array as type, then you say that you want `"images" : [ 
"https....."
]` and now you say you want an object?

Comment: @JeremyThille if using array not working then can i use object?

Comment: You need to use lodash or hard code to process your post data before add it in to moongdb...

Comment: @TruongDang can you please update my code with answer?

Comment: `"https://images.pexels.com/photos/346768/pexels-photo-346768.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb","https://images.pexels.com/photos/287240/pexels-photo-287240.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
` How You are posting it to a backend you are getting an improper result because there may something wrong while sending data.

Comment: @TruongDang No, you don't _need_ to use Lodash. I have never used Lodash, ever, and there's really few things Lodash can do that can't easily be done with ES6. This problem looks like a simple type casting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `req.body.images` is stringified. I believe it is a string containing many values, not an array. When you post that to MongoDB, since you specified that `images` must be an array, it saves it as an array of strigified values.

So, blind guess, but I believe you are posting (client-side) something like :

```
$.post("/save", { images : JSON.stringify(imagesArray) } )
```

when you should just post your array as is :

```
$.post("/save", { images : imagesArray} )
```

But it's hard to know for sure, because we don't have the front-end code or even `console.log(req.body.images)`